# Problems using Chrome Webdriver on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've got problems when using Chrome Webdriver in Raspberry Pi. I downloaded and installed builds of chromium browser, driver and codecs from [here](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-chromium-builds/+archive/ubuntu/stage/+build/14482955). (Built files located at the bottom of the page)

I checked that the packages were successfully installed on the device:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep chromium
ii  chromium-browser                      65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1        armhf        Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome
ii  chromium-chromedriver                 65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1        armhf        WebDriver driver for the Chromium Browser
ii  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra          65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu0.14.04.1        armhf        Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
rc  rpi-chromium-mods                     20190613                              armhf        Raspberry Pi-specific mods to Chromium
```

...and also checked that the files were installed at `/usr/lib/chromium-browser'

```
$ ls -al /usr/lib/chromium-browser/ | grep chrom
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   813215 Mar 22  2018 chrome_100_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1083947 Mar 22  2018 chrome_200_percent.pak
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  6334180 Mar 23  2018 chromedriver
-r-sr-xr-x  1 root root    13728 Mar 23  2018 chrome-sandbox
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 91760672 Mar 23  2018 chromium-browser
```

Then I created selenium-test.py, the script I tried to execute chromedriver.

```
# selenium-test.py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

But when I ran the script, the script just raised "unknown error".

```
$ python3 selenium-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium-test.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35 (0),platform=Linux 4.19.50-v7+ armv7l)
```

What is the problem on this process? I have installed correct builds, version do match, and used right script.

Answer (score 3):

Well I've just solved this problem so quickly... and answering myself in case someone faces the same problem.

Adding options when initializing the driver does the work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

print('Success')
```

Comment: Count yourself lucky :) I am sure you're still clueless how and why it worked

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks : ) I assume that the reason is because pi cannot display extra chromium browser windows, so I should give options such as headless whether I need it or not